# Migration spring boot (security) 2.0.8 to 2.3.12

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to update an old project from Spring Boot **2.0.8** to **2.3.12**. But I am having problem with spring security.

`pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

My `spring-security.xml` file working on **2.0.8**:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="false" pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="amAdmin" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/login" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login
        login-page="/admin/login"
        default-target-url="/admin/"
        login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/admin/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-url="/admin/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/admin/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <!-- <csrf/> -->
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<http auto-config="false" pattern="/private/**" authentication-manager-ref="amUsers" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/private/login" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/private/getPassword" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/private/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/private**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login
        login-page="/private/login"
        default-target-url="/private/account/"
        login-processing-url="/private/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/private/login?error"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-url="/private/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/private/login?logout" />
    <!-- 1209600 -->
    <remember-me
        user-service-ref="usUsuarios"
        token-validity-seconds="1209600"
        remember-me-parameter="remember-me"
        data-source-ref="myDataSource" />
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager id="amAdmin" >
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="encryptedPass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager id="amUsers">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        <jdbc-user-service id="usUsuarios" data-source-ref="myDataSource"
            users-by-username-query=
                "select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username, role from user_roles where username = ?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

The following error occurs at startup (**2.3.12**): `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot define alias 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' for name 'amUsers': It is already registered for name 'amAdmin'.`

I have changed it to java annotations, but only the one with **@Order(1)** works:

`UserSecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public UserSecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.userAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/private/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/private/account/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/private/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/private/login?error")
                .successHandler(this.savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()

                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/private/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/private/login?logout")
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private/login", "/private/getPassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/private/*", "/private**").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .and()

                .rememberMe()
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsServiceImpl)
                .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600)
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
        ;
    }
}
```

`AdminSecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class AdminSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public AdminSecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    private AdminAuthenticationProvider adminAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.adminAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/admin/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()

                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/admin/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login?logout")
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/*", "/admin**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and()

                .csrf().disable()
        ;
    }
}
```

I have not been able to find an example with this exact casuistry. And the ones I have found have not worked

Comment: your new code does not include `amUsers` and `amAdmin` and thats where your problem lies, but since you have not included anything that contains those two names in your new code, then this is unsolvable. So the simple question is, what are those, and where is the code that includes those names? and why havnt you posted that code since thats clearly seems to be where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it modifying my xml. I have merged the two `authentication-provider` and referenced the name of the `authentication-manager` in the http settings (Spring beans are not required):

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/login" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/admin/login"
            default-target-url="/admin/"
            login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/admin/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/admin/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/admin/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <!-- <csrf/> -->
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <http auto-config="false" pattern="/private/**" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/private/login" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/private/getPassword" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/private/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/private**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/private/login"
            default-target-url="/private/account/"
            login-processing-url="/private/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/private/login?error"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/private/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/private/login?logout" />
        <!-- 1209600 -->
        <remember-me
            user-service-ref="usUsuarios"
            token-validity-seconds="1209600"
            remember-me-parameter="remember-me"
            data-source-ref="myDataSource" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" >
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="encryptedPass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service id="usUsuarios" data-source-ref="myDataSource"
                users-by-username-query=
                    "select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query=
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```